# How can I convert HeadersInit into a type of Object<string,string>?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Long story short, I need to convert a `RequestInit`'s headers into a different data type that another library can understand. This library expects the headers to be `Object<string, string>`. I was hoping I could simply do something like:

```
headers: {
 ...init?.headers,
},
```

As expected, it wasn't this simple. I believe it's because some of the values in `init.headers` are of type number. How can I convert these so that TypeScript won't complain?

Answer (score 0):

As `Headers` constructor is made out of `HeadersInit`,

```
function headersInitToRecord(headersInit: HeadersInit) {
    return Object.fromEntries(new Headers(headersInit).entries());
}
```

Or, if you want to support `undefined`,

```
function headersInitToRecord1(headersInit?: HeadersInit | undefined) {
    // new Headers(undefined) is fine
    return Object.fromEntries(new Headers(headersInit).entries());
}
```

Or, if you want to support `undefined` returning `undefined`,

```
function headersInitToRecord2(headersInit?: HeadersInit | undefined) {
    return headersInit && Object.fromEntries(new Headers(headersInit).entries());
}
```

---

[tests playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYEMAmqBOBnASTBigBU4AlVCOHTACjS10OKgC5EAJDbfIkgEpEAbwBQiSYhyooIHEgDyAIwBW1KADpgOOAFsAomCg4YqPPTCoA7t14tG9-m0GCA3GIC+YsTTB44ABtUTUC4AHN6CSkmPlYScioaOnoAbVSAcmA4OAyAGkQM5XQcDIBdMsE86MlYlgEySmpaBhFsuE4ikozPKpqUJ3jGpJbLGztmfDTM9vzC4tKK12rBIA):

```
console.log(
    headersInitToRecord([['foo', 'bar']]),
    headersInitToRecord({foo: 'bar'}),
    headersInitToRecord(new Headers([['foo', 'bar']])),
)
```